# How to do a lookup on a Loki Name Service (LNS) record?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, loki-name-service

When a loki name service record is created, how does one query the loki blockchain to see where does the LNS resolve to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loki cli wallet has a new command titled `lns_print_name_to_owners`

```
lns_print_name_to_owners lnsname
```